# How to make perload for images in a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is hard to find solution in Google, it's related to some keywords.

How ever, how can i show loading image for `img` in page?

I find this example:

```
<img src"blabla" onloadstart=" " onloadend=" ">
```

but how use it ?

Comment: you forget '=' <img src="blabla" onloadstart=" " onloadend=" ">, it's not about your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want loading background image for image before showing, right?

Use this css, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Hp23E/

```
img{
    background:url(http://cloud4.faout.com/imagecache/EV02/images3/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```